# using "daff" packages in R (or data comparing in R)

Tags: r, compare

I want a comparison and visualization of two datasets. 
The results from using the `daff` package for a total of 369 data are as follows.

```
render_diff( diff_data(data_ref = data1, data = data2, options(encoding="UTF-8")),pretty = TRUE)
```

When run with full data, some data define that the row itself has changed while others find modified.

[image]

[image]

If a portion of the data has been implemented, the modified part is well identified.

[image]

I think this is a matter of number of data.
The exact definitions of deleted, added and modified by `daff` package were not found.
I want to see all the data changes in the form of modified. 
Let me know if you can solve this problem.
Or recommend a package that detects all changes in data.

`diffobj`, `arsenal`, and `compareDF` packages were tried and looked more uncomfortable than `daff`.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what exactly is the problem? It is not entirely clear from your description.

Comment: I didn't quite understand which case was modified or added. You can confirm that you want to judge added, deleted when executing the whole thing, or modified when performing a part. I thought the ability to categorize the entire data seemed to be compromised. I want to see all the data in the form of modified.